# MAGENTO Error: dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: magento

my magento report this issue.

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 518908518811

In log:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:65:
"dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract";i:1;s:1412:"
#0 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#2 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1386): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#3 /var/www/html/sound/shop/app/Mage.php(461): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#4 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#5 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#6 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(598): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#7 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(456): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#8 /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(342): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#9 /var/www/html/sound/shop/app/Mage.php(642): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/sound/shop/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
";s:3:"url";s:20:"/shop/checkout/cart/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";}
```

Comment: Did this error happen after you installed a certain module?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear cache and reindex all indexes.
2. Check if your database settings are correct.
3. Make sure to set var/ folder and subfolder permissions to 777.

Comment: reindex all indexes about what?

Comment: System > Index Management > Select All > Submit (Reindex Data)